# How to use coordinates returned by one function in another function?

Tags: python, user-interface, mouseevent, mouseclick-event

I am trying to write a function to draw a line between two coordinates returned from the get_position() function, which returns the coordinates of a mouse click.

**Code to return position of mouse click:**

```
def get_position(self, ev):
        return(ev.pos().x(), ev.pos().y())
```

I am stuck on the next part. This does not work and gives me an error. I am not sure how to use the coordinates that are returned. Any pointers:?

```
def draw():
    coordinates = get_position()
```

Comment: What is `getPos()`? If you call `coords = get_position(someEvent)` the `return` value will be stored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def draw():
    coordinates = getPos()
```

Why do you call getPos(), if your function name is get_position?
Also, you have "self" argument in your code, that's mean it's part of the class, right? So here are 2 ways: one is to create an instance of this class in draw function, and other is to put draw also in the class.
The last one can be done in this way:

```
def draw(self, ev):
    coordinates = self.get_position(ev)
```

Also if you want to call get_position, you need to get to it argument ev. So I place it in draw argument function.
But this can not work in your situation. So can you add more information? Place more code. And which error do you get?